# Is -3 always a quadratic residue in Z/p*Z for a prime p>3?

Tags: number-theory

Looking at the Legendre symbol:

$$\left(\frac{-3}{p}\right) = \left(\frac{-1}{p}\right)\left(\frac{3}{p}\right) = (-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\left(\frac{3}{p}\right) = (-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}(-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}\cdot\frac{3-1}{2}}\left(\frac{p}{3}\right) = \left(\frac{p}{3}\right),$$

and since $p$ is an odd prime greater than $3,$ then $\left(\frac{p}{3}\right) = 1,$  and so $-3$ is a quadratic residue *modulo* $p$.

I know I'm wrong, but I can't find my mistake.
Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Did you mean: $$-{{3}\over{p}}=-{{3}\over{p^2}}={{3\,\left(-1\right)^{p-{{
 1}\over{2}}}}\over{p}}={{p\,\left(-1\right)^{p+{{5\,\left(p-{{1
 }\over{2}}\right)}\over{2}}-{{1}\over{2}}}}\over{3}}$$ ?

Comment: Where does the implicatin $p\gt3\implies(\frac{p}{3})=1$ come from?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I don't know how to format to make it clearer, but I just used the multiplicative property and the reciprocative property of the Legendre symbol, making a mistake along the way.

Comment: @awllower if p>3 is prime then it can't be 0mod(3), therefore it has to be either 1 or 2 mod(3), both of which are quadratic residues mod(3).

Comment: You write $(-3|p) = ... = (p|3)$, and that much is fine. Your reasoning goes off the rails when you write $(p|3) \Rightarrow p > 3$ and then $p > 3 \Rightarrow (p|3) = 1$. This makes no sense. Do you mean $p \not= 3$ rather than $p > 3$? Concerning your latest comment to your question, 2 is *NOT* a quadratic residue mod 3!

Comment: But $2$ is not a residue module $3,$ while $0$ is.

Comment: You guys are right, for some reason I had it in my head that 2 is a quadratic residue modulo 3. For some reason the question I'm looking at calls to prove that (-3/p) = 1 if p = 1mod(6) or -1 if p = 5mod(6). Is it sufficient to say that (-3/p) = 1 if p = 1mod(3) or -1 if p = 2mod(3) ? Thanks for the help!

Comment: @MickLH: The notation is indeed confusing for those not familiar with the [Legendre symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in concluding that $\left(\frac{p}{3}\right)=1$ just because $p$ is an odd prime greater than $3.$ If $p\equiv2\pmod{3},$ then in fact $\left(\frac{p}{3}\right)=-1.$

**Added**: Given that you're looking at odd primes $p>3,$ you can indeed conclude that exactly one of the following holds:

- $p\equiv 1\pmod3,$ in which case $\left(\frac{p}{3}\right)=1,$ or
- $p\equiv 2\pmod3,$ in which case $\left(\frac{p}{3}\right)=-1.$

In the first case, either $p\equiv1\pmod6$ or $p\equiv4\pmod6,$ the latter of which we can rule out. (Why?) In the second case, either $p\equiv2\pmod6$ or $p\equiv5\pmod6,$ the former of which we can rule out. (Why?) Beyond that, though, we can't narrow things down any further.

Comment: For example, $-3 \equiv 2 \pmod{5}$ is not a quadratic residue.